# Error Code: 1364. Field 'AddressID' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql

I'm receiving the above error when I try to perform the following query:

```
insert into person_address(PersonID)
select personID from person;
```

So basically what I'm trying to achieve is to insert data from my primary keys into my foreign keys as they were not linked when data was first entered into the person table.

Am I correct in inserting this data and then creating a stored procedure with an update query to update these tables in future?

Table structures:

person_address (to contain foreign keys of both person and address tables and where I'm trying to insert the values)

```
AddressID   int(11) NO  PRI     
PersonID    int(11) YES MUL
```

person:

```
personID    int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
Forename    varchar(30) YES         
Surname varchar(30) YES         
PhoneNumber varchar(15) YES         
Email   varchar(100)    YES
```

address:

```
addressID   int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
line1   varchar(100)    YES         
line2   varchar(100)    YES         
county  varchar(50) YES         
postcode    varchar(8)  YES         
country varchar(20) YES
```

Comment: you should update if you have already data

Comment: It doesn't yet have data because of this issue. But I will be updating after this has been inputted

Comment: show your all table structure and  what you want. it is not clear here

Comment: Table structures have been added.

Comment: In a many-to-many relation table, the primary key should be both columns, not just `AddressID`. Otherwise, you can't have two people at the same address (like a husband and wife).

Comment: So basically PersonID needs to be a PK? Once that is done then it will allow me to insert the data?

Comment: you have to add one more Id as PRI  if  you need person_address. but you should add personID as FK in address table. it is the good way

Comment: It is already identified as an FK but it will add as an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your `person_address` table contains a column named `AddressID`. It is defined as `NOT NULL` but you do not provide a value when you insert a record.

So either provide a value in your insert statement or define a default value for the column.

I guess your  `AddressID` column is the primary key of your table. So you probably forgot to define it as AUTO INCREMENT.

Comment: AddressID is linked to a PK from another table, should i be inputting into the FK instead of the column?

Comment: I don't quite get it. Maybe you can add example data and expected output to the question

Comment: So table 'Address' has 'addressID' with the data being just '1' and another '2' I inserted this data into a table called 'person_address- which holds the foreign key of both the 'address' and person 'table'. This also has 2 linked columns (to the FK's) being 'AddressID' and 'PersonID'. When I inputted the data from address(addressID) to person_address(AddressID) then it worked. However this does not, if this table is just to hold FK's do I need 2 columns linked to these?

Comment: You need to have both - an AddressID and a PersonID to insert into person_address. Otherwise it does not make sense inserting at all.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to achieve and these both exist already. This is the table structure for person_address: ```AddressID int(11) NO PRI  
PersonID int(11) YES MUL  ```

Comment: There's no way to automatically know which addressID goes with each personID, since thw whole point of this table is to add the relationship. You should be getting this information from the user, not trying to insert all personID's at once.